# Spring security error in remoting calls from embedded Flex application in Spring MVC page

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, spring-security, blazeds

I wish someone can help me with this one. I have a Spring MVC application (Spring 3) running perfectly fine with Spring Security 3, we are now adding support for Flex and added BlazeDS to the application and Spring Integration (1.5.0 M2), all started working fine until we wanted to integrate authentication through Spring Security. The Flex application is a "mini" UI that serves as a P2P chat (through messaging) between two users and it is embedded in a JSP page in the Spring MVC application, what we want to do is ensure (from the Flex application) that the user is logged in before showing the chat UI. The authentication is done from the Spring MVC application (a web form) and it works fine, but every time we access to the Spring MVC page that holds the Flex application and make a remoting call from Flex to get the current user details we get an exception:

```
flex.messaging.security.SecurityException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

We assumed that the remoting request (made from an authenticated session) will be somehow picked up and recognized and that the Flex client doesn't need to authenticate again. What could be wrong here? Here is my spring security config and my flex configuration file as well as the web.xml:

security.xml:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">          
            <sec:filter-chain filters="none" pattern="/styles/**" />
            <sec:filter-chain filters="none" pattern="/js/**" />
            <sec:filter-chain filters="none" pattern="/images/**" />
            <sec:filter-chain 
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                    logoutFilter,
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,
                    anonymousAuthenticationFilter,
                    exceptionTranslationFilter,
                    menuLoaderRequestFilter,
                    filterSecurityInterceptor" 
                pattern="/web/**" />
            <sec:filter-chain 
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,
                    exceptionTranslationFilter" 
                pattern="/do_login" />              
            <sec:filter-chain 
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                    logoutFilter,
                    exceptionTranslationFilter" 
                pattern="/do_logout" />
        </sec:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />

    <bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager"
                ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/do_login"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <ref bean="loginFailureHandler" />
        </property>
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <ref bean="loginSuccessHandler" />
        </property>
        <property name="usernameParameter" value="login_user" />
        <property name="passwordParameter" value="login_password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginFailureHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/web/login?error=login.failure"/>
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException</value>
                    </key>
                    <value>/web/login?error=login.database.failure</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginSuccessHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/web/index"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="userAttribute"
                value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <property name="key" value="AD17JFJ005P00Z7MK" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutFilter" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <!-- the post-logout destination -->
        <constructor-arg value="/web/login?success=login.loggedout"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <array>
                <ref bean="logoutHandler" />
            </array>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/do_logout"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoutHandler" 
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />

    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint"
            ref="mainEntryPoint"/>
        <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="mainEntryPoint" 
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint">         
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>hasHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')</value>                      
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="ajaxEntryPoint"/>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>hasHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-amf')</value>
                    </key>
                    <ref bean="flexEntryPoint" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>          
        <property name="defaultEntryPoint" ref="defaultEntryPoint" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entryPointTemplate" abstract="true">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/web/login"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ajaxEntryPoint" parent="entryPointTemplate"
            class="com.saes.support.security.AjaxAuthenticationEntryPoint" >
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultEntryPoint" parent="entryPointTemplate"
            class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">       
    </bean>

    <bean id="flexEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.flex.security3.FlexAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
            class="com.saes.support.security.SAESAccessDeniedHandler">
        <property name="errorPage" 
                value="/web/errors/accessDenied"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="authenticationManager"
                ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="decisionManager"/>
        <property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/web/profile/**" 
                    access="ROLE_USER" />
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/web/doctor/**" 
                    access="ROLE_DOCTOR" />
            </sec:filter-security-metadata-source>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="menuLoaderRequestFilter"
                class="com.saes.security.menu.MenuPermissionsAdapterRequestFilter">
    </bean> 

    <bean id="decisionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false" />
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
                <ref bean="authenticatedVoter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="roleVoter" 
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />

    <bean id="authenticatedVoter" 
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />

    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" 
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService">
            <ref bean="userDetailsService" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" 
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="key" value="AD17JFJ005P00Z7MK"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
                <ref bean="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

flex-servlet.xml:

```
<flex:message-broker 
        services-config-path="/WEB-INF/config/flex/services-config.xml">

        <flex:secured authentication-manager="authenticationManager"
         access-decision-manager="decisionManager">
            <flex:secured-endpoint-path pattern="**/messagebroker/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        </flex:secured>

    </flex:message-broker>
```

web.xml:

```
    <context-param>     
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring/persistence.xml 
/WEB-INF/config/spring/security.xml
/WEB-INF/config/spring/services.xml
/WEB-INF/config/spring/facade.xml
/WEB-INF/config/spring/validator.xml  
/WEB-INF/config/flex/flex-context.xml                               
    </param-value>
  </context-param>   
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>  
  <servlet>     
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet>     
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flex</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>    
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> 
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>    
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/critical-error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>  
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>    
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/errors/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

And here is the relevant part of the Flex code:

```
<s:ChannelSet id="chatChannelSet">
        <s:StreamingAMFChannel url="http://192.168.1.3:8080/MyApp/messagebroker/streamamf">             
        </s:StreamingAMFChannel>            
    </s:ChannelSet>

    <s:ChannelSet id="remotingChannelSet">
        <s:AMFChannel url="http://192.168.1.3:8080/MyApp/messagebroker/amf">
        </s:AMFChannel>
    </s:ChannelSet>
<s:RemoteObject id="remoteService" 
                    destination="remoteService"
                    channelSet="{remotingChannelSet}">          
    </s:RemoteObject>

var asyncCall:AsyncToken = remoteService.getTicketForCurrentUser();
asyncCall.addResponder(new Responder(getTicket_Result, getTicket_Fault));
```

The previous code always ends up in the Fault handler with the error mentioned at the beginning of the cuestion

Other configuration files:

services-config.xml:

```
<services-config> 

<services>       
    <service-include file-path="messaging-config.xml" />        
</services>

<channels>
    <channel-definition id="my-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
    </channel-definition>

    <channel-definition id="streaming-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.StreamingAMFChannel">
        <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/streamamf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.StreamingAMFEndpoint"/>
        <properties>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes> 
            <max-streaming-clients>10</max-streaming-clients> 
            <server-to-client-heartbeat-millis>5000</server-to-client-heartbeat-millis> 
            <user-agent-settings>
                <user-agent match-on="MSIE" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="3" /> 
                <user-agent match-on="Firefox" kickstart-bytes="2048" max-streaming-connections-per-session="3" /> 
            </user-agent-settings>
        </properties>
    </channel-definition>      
</channels>

<logging>
    <target class="flex.messaging.log.ConsoleTarget" level="Debug">
        <properties>
            <prefix>[BlazeDS] </prefix>
            <includeDate>false</includeDate>
            <includeTime>false</includeTime>
            <includeLevel>false</includeLevel>
            <includeCategory>false</includeCategory>
        </properties>
        <filters>
            <pattern>Endpoint.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Service.*</pattern>
            <pattern>Configuration</pattern>
        </filters>
    </target>
</logging>

<system>
    <redeploy>
        <enabled>false</enabled>           
    </redeploy>
</system>
```

messaging-config.xml:

```
<service id="message-service" 
class="flex.messaging.services.MessageService">

<adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="actionscript" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.ActionScriptAdapter" default="true" />
</adapters>

<destination id="chat-destination">
    <properties>
        <server>
            <message-time-to-live>0</message-time-to-live>
            <allow-subtopics>true</allow-subtopics>
            <subtopic-separator>.</subtopic-separator>
            <disallow-wildcard-subtopics>true</disallow-wildcard-subtopics>
        </server>           
    </properties>
    <channels>
        <channel ref="streaming-amf" />
    </channels>
</destination>

<default-channels>
    <channel ref="streaming-amf"/>
</default-channels>
```

Comment: No flex code? If so, I might have to remove the flex tag of this question.

Comment: @J_A_X the Flex code has been added to the question :)

Comment: "We assumed that the remoting request (made from an authenticated session) will be recognized." The RemoteObject call made from Flex to the server will pass all the cookies set from the server. Usually cookies are used to match a client request with a server side session. I'm a Java noob; but I assume that BlazeDS and your other Java stuff would have be running in the same "app pool" to share sessions. The Flex client also needs to be served off same URL domain that the JSP page is or it won't have cookies to access session. Not an answer; but I hope it helps puts you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not a server guy, but I'm not seeing a destination in any of the server configuration, while the Flex code is referencing 'remoteService'. Am I missing something?  Furthermore, if you need authentication, I'm not seeing a [ChannelSet.login](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_security_5.html) anywhere.

Comment: @J_A_X, by "a destination in any of the server configuration" do you mean the services-config.xml and messaging-config.xml BlazeDS configuration files? I will add them as well just in case

Comment: @J_A_X given that the RemoteObject call should pass all the cookies and allow the server to match the user session I guess the issue is more related to the configuration of Spring Security, I will make some more tests to see what could be happening but this is driving me nuts! :(

Comment: @J_A_X added the other configuration files maybe the ones you were asking for :)

Comment: I'm still not seeing the 'remoteService' destination.  I see 'chat-destination'.

Comment: @J_A_X the "remoteService" destination is a Java class annotated with @Service and @RemoteDestination("remoteService") which gets loaded by Spring with a <context:component-scan /> directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging into the configuration I found the problem, and I will post the solution for everyone who might need it. I had to explicitly tell Spring Security to include the "securityContextPersistenceFilter" in the filter chain for my "/messagebroker/**" urls so the security context gets properly populated with the authentication information (as we assumed from the beginning). The configuration was added to the "springSecurityFilterChain" bean as follows:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <!-- other filter chain maps and options here (see the entire file in comment above -->
            <sec:filter-chain 
            filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" 
            pattern="/messagebroker/**" />
</bean>
```

After adding that filter chain configuration to the Spring Security filter all requests from the Flex UI where automatically populated with the existing authentication created from a previous login through the Spring MVC web form.

Answer (score 0):

To give a quick answer - can you set up your Flex stuff to piggyback on an existing Spring Security HTML-based login form? Yes, absolutely you can. I've done it and it works quite nicely if you have some of your app that needs to be protected but doesn't get served through a flex app.

I'm NOT using the

```
<flex:secured>
```

part of the the message-broker config (it didn't exist when I first set this up, perhaps I could switch to it now but since my setup is working I don't feel any strong need to at the moment). I have my my messagebroker url pattern set up to be secured. My messagebroker is secured like so:

(the swf-loading-page is just a placeholder name for a page that wraps the swf... and .do is mapped to my view resolver)

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/swf-loading-page.do*" access="ROLE_USER,     
<security:intercept-url pattern="/messagebroker/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

When on the flex side you call:

```
 remoteService.getTicketForCurrentUser()
```

What gets called on the server in the java side?

For mine, I do something similar - I pull out the local user to return it to the flex client (to display the current logged in user, etc) -

On your Java side you can use the SpringSecurityContextHolder to get the SecurityContext and then from the SecurityContext you can pull out the

```
//These packages are where you can hook into the authentication from your service
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
...
SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
```

If you your your app server with jpda debugging you can set a breakpoint on that method and peek into your security context and make sure it is being correctly populated (but it seems that it is not - which is odd)

Comment: Hi @Ryan, thanks for your answer, your solution worked as expected :) but I managed to track down the problem on my configuration, see my comment below, I will post the solution just in case any other person runs into the same problem as me. Thank you very much anyway :)

Comment: Had to post my solution here in a comment because Stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question before 8 hours.

Comment: The solution involves adding the "securityContextPersistenceFilter" in the Spring Security filter chain for all my Flex requests. I will post the entire solution later because the explanation is too big for a comment. As soon as the system lets me answer my own question I will post it here